# Unable to connect to MySQL server from VPS but able to from desktop

Tags: mysql, database, remote-access, vps, mysql-error-1064

I'm connecting to my MySQL server that is hosted remotely using the MySQL-connector package in python. I created a user for my home computer with my home IP address which works just fine and can connect without any issues whatsoever.

But whenever I've tried to either:

a). Create a new user, grant privileges and connect from a secondary VPS

or

b). Create a new user that is on the MySQL server VPS (localhost), granted privileges and then tried to connect to the MySQL server

I've time over time encountered this error:

```
1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

(when I tried option a the IP would be my VPS's IP).

I really have no clue how I would go about fixing this. My bind-address is set to 0.0.0.0 and my firewall is inactive/open to everyone on port 3306.

If any of you got any suggestions on how I can fix this please let me know

Comment: I suppose you need to add the user `username@ip_of_vps` or `username@%` but the second way (wildcard host) is not safe

Comment: @myscode Yeah tried that already when I tried with another VPS but now that I'm trying to connect from the same VPS im just using localhost instead and it's still not workign